# YouTube動画をブログで再生するには、提供されているコードを使用する必要がある？

Tags: youtube

**どこかで下記内容を見た(ような気がする)のですが、思い出せません**
・YouTube動画をiframe以外でブログに埋め込むのは規約違反

**YouTube動画埋め込みコードについて**
・ブログへ埋め込む際、このコード使用は必須でしょうか？
・あるいは、独自で実装しても良い？
・YouTube動画をブログへ埋め込む際、提供されているコード以外を使用してコーディングしても良いでしょうか？？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[YouTube利用規約](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=ja&gl=JP)

> 4. 本サービスの一般的な利用--許可及び制限事項
>      お客様は、本サービス自体の動画再生ページ、Embeddable Player、又はその他YouTubeが明示的に認めた手段以外のあらゆる技術及び手段を通じて、 本コンテンツにアクセスしないことに合意します。